# NSData length of an Image compressed with UIImageJPEGRepresentation()

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata

We know the image can be compressed with the Method `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` as in the following codes.

```
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageResized, 0.5);
    NSLog(@"imgData.length :%d",imgData.length);

    imageResized = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
    NSData *imgData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageResized, 1);

    NSLog(@"imgData2.length :%d",imgData2.length);
```

The log is:

```
2013-02-25 00:33:14.756 MyApp[1119:440b] imgData.length :371155
2013-02-25 00:33:20.988 MyApp[1119:440b] imgData2.length :1308415
```

What Im confused is that why the `length` of `imgData` and `imgData2` are different. In my App, the image should be uploaded to the server. Should I upload the `NSData` to the server for saving storage? Is it possible for an Android phone to download the `NSData` and convert it to an image? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why would you expect them to be of the same size? Do you know what compression means?

Comment: @H2CO3 plz take a look at the accepted answer, and you will see why am I confused:) Yes, I know what's compression:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You start with a `UIImage` of some size (say 1024x768). This takes 1024x768x4 byes in memory. Then you compress it with a factor of 0.5 and get 371,155 bytes.

You then create a new `UIImage` with the compressed data. This is still a 1024x768 (or whatever) `UIImage` so it now takes the same amount of memory (1024x768x4) as the original image. You then convert it to a new JPG with less compression giving you 1,308,415 bytes.

Even though you create an uncompressed version of the compressed image, the number of bytes comes from converting the full sized `UIImage`. The 2nd, uncompressed image, though bigger, will still have the same lower quality of the compressed image.

Since your data represents a JPG, anything that downloads the data will be able to treat the data as a JPG, including an Android phone.

Comment: but i wanna know why after`imageResized = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData]`, we get the original Image. That's interesting. @luyuan @rmaddy

Comment: @demon You don't get the original image. Did you read my answer? It explains how the 2nd image is different from the original.

Comment: @rmaddy i had readed it and known it's a new image, but what i wonder is that why we create a new image with compressed data, then we get data from this new image again, but what we get is the origin date length.

Comment: A `UIImage` in memory is width x height x 4 bytes. It doesn't matter what the file size is. A `UIImage` is an uncompressed bitmap.

Comment: Maybe i got the point that confuse me. what 'UIImageJPEGRepresentation' compress did it nothing with memory, but something else, right?

Answer (score 3):

The number of bytes is bigger for the second image because you passed a much higher compression quality value to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. Higher quality takes more bytes.

The file once uploaded to a server will be a standard JPEG file, viewable by any device, including Android.